# How to convert jiffies to percentages from virt plugin

Tags: openstack, grafana, collectd

i have installed collectd on our compute node. and enabled virt plugin inside it. we push the result to influxdb. we try to get the instance CPU utilization to be displayed inside grafana. however, we can see the output is using jiffies. Can anyone advise, how can we display correctly the graph in percentage instead of jiffies.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a visualisation which does a derivative